# perm/comb problem on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations, combinations

I have seen similar problems and yet can't seem to find the answer for this specific one.

Count the number of functions

$$ \varphi: \{-9,-8,\ldots,-5\}\to \{-9,-8,\ldots,-5\}$$

so that

1) $\varphi$ is one-to-one and $\varphi(-8) = -5$

2) $\varphi$ is one-to-one and $\varphi(-8) \ne -5$.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Note that these two partition the set of all bijections on the set, so you can use complementary counting to find the second after you get the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping from a $5$ element set to a $5$ element set.

1) Since we must have $\varphi(-8)=-5$, we need to assign $4$ elements of the domain. In order to make $\varphi$ one-to-one, each of these $4$ elements must map to a unique element of the codomain. Thus we have $4$ options for $\varphi(-9)$ (since it can't be equal to $-5$), and then $3$ options for $\varphi(-7)$ (since it can't be equal to $-5$ or $\varphi(-9)$), and so forth. In total we have $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=4!$ different functions.

2) I suggest counting how many one-to-one functions there are without any restrictions, and then subtracting that number from the one we obtained in (1). I'll let you work out the details.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting 15 elements for (-9,...-5) from, but nevertheless I figured out the logic from your work. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Haha I guess I misread it as $\{-9,\ldots,5\}$. Happy to help!